# Run command using php curl

Tags: php, curl

How i can run this commando curl:

**curl -F "param01=value01" -F "param02=value02" -v http://example.com/Home/Login**

Using PHP ?

Doubt is because the parameter -F, I never used it...

Comment: My doubt is because "-F", I can not find the equivalent in PHP

Comment: Updated my reply for you to include what -F means and how to do this in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

curl man page:

> -F, --form
>
> (HTTP) **This lets curl emulate a filled-in form** in which a user has
>   pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the
>   Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This enables
>   uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a
>   file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content
>   part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The
>   difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get attached in
>   the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get
>   the contents for that text field from a file.

You'll use the POST example, at the bottom of my response.

If param01 and param02 are GET/url parameters, this will work.

```
<?php

// Setup our curl handler
if (!$ch = curl_init())
{
    die("cURL package not installed in PHP");
}

$value1 = urlencode("something");
$value2 = urlencode("something");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com/Home/Login?param01='.$value1.'&param02='.$value2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE); // TRUE if we want to track the request string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // TRUE to return the transfer as a string

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_error($ch) != "")
{
    die("Error with cURL installation: " . curl_error($ch));
}
else
{
    // Do something with the response
    echo $response;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

If they are POST (form data):

```
<?php

// Setup our curl handler
if (!$ch = curl_init())
{
    die("cURL package not installed in PHP");
}

$value1 = urlencode("something");
$value2 = urlencode("something");

$data = array(
    'param1' => $value1,
    'param1' => $value2,
)

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com/Home/Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE); // TRUE if we want to track the request string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // TRUE to return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_error($ch) != "")
{
    die("Error with cURL installation: " . curl_error($ch));
}
else
{
    // Do something with the response
    echo $response;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need and more:

http://php.net/curl

simple example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.example.com/yourscript.php",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'field1' => 'some date',
        'field2' => 'some other data',
    ),
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig)
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```